# How to check my app on client's simulator

Tags: iphone, simulator

Is there any way that client can check my app on his simulator what should i do for that...I do not want to send code of my application to him.....

I know adhoc is required to test on device but here i want to run on his simulator...

Comment: @Linuxmint--I was helped but confused about which one should i accept...wait 30 sec

Comment: @Online: hehehe, sometimes its hard to pick one.

Comment: @Linuxmint--Correct...Thanks...again

Comment: @Online: No problem, anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go: Macintosh HD\Users\ *YourUserName*\Library\Application Support\iPhone Simulator\ *iPhoneVersionNumber*\Applications:

Then you have to look through each *"AJ2783FO29ZO38-WSOHF93"* weirdly named  folder and find the one that is your app folder. Copy it and put it in the same place on your clients computer.

I have not personally tried this myself. Let me know if you need any other information!

Comment: Won't work, as the long magic number folder/directory name seems to be different for every developer and every app ID.

Comment: @hotpaw2 : He could at least try it, as its the only possible option. Did you try it yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Build your app for the iPhone Simulator (iOS 4.2 on this example) and run it from Xcode. 
The app should now be stored in a coded subfolder under 
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/ (e.g. ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/E5548CB9-0A50-49EF-92AB-39F10820D9D6/)

Send your client the whole subfolder (E5548CB9-0A50-49EF-92AB-39F10820D9D6) and tell him to copy it over to /Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/, then run the iPhone simulator. He should be able to see the app on the simulator and run it. Note that the app will probably appear on the second 'page' of the simulator, so you client may need to scroll to the right.

You can test this between different machines at your own office prior to sending it to your client. He'll have to have Mac OS X 10.6 with the latest iOS SDK installed of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Apple supported method.  However if you quit your Simulator after installing your app, zip up your entire Library Applications Support directory for the iPhone Simulator, send it to the client and have the client replaces theirs (after a backup of their Library, or maybe running in another Mac User account).  Then when they start their Simulator (has to be from the exact same Xcode/SDK installer as yours), they will see a clone of your Simulator, with your app installed.

Trying to copy just the app bundle may or may not work, as some versions of the Simulator depend on metadata elsewhere within the App Support dir.